# Bootstrap 3 - two columns - div vertical align

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I have for element:
- box-1 and box-2 are col-1
- box-3 and box-4 are col-2

box 1, 2, 4 are text, box-3 is an image.
The two columns have different heights.

How can I force the vertical alignment of box-2 so to have box-2 and box-4 with the same bottom line?

At the moment i found this js [Sam152/Javascript-Equal-Height-Responsive-Rows](https://github.com/Sam152/Javascript-Equal-Height-Responsive-Rows), so i can force the two columns at the same height. I don't know if this is a step in the right way.

Here the basic code (without the js element):

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- col 1 -->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div id="box-1">
                        <h1>1<br>TEXT</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div id="box-2">
                        <h1>2<br>TEXT</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- col 2 -->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div id="box-3">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/480/360" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="box-4">
                        <a href="">
                            <h1>4<br>TEXT</h1>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: ...instead of using two columns, use two rows to achieve what you are looking for

Comment: I try to link below a picture of the layout. The probelm is the space gap between the boxes. If I use two rows, i'll have too much space between the boxes.
[link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/267117/temp/bootstrap-div-vertical-align.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you basically have to make box-1 the same height as box-3. you can do it manually with css or you can use jQuery to make 2 divs the same height.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var Height = $('#box-3').height();
        $('#box-1').height(Height);
    });
</script>
```

make sure you dont have elements that add extra margin or padding to box-1:

```
#box-1 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

this will get rid of all padding and margin of the elements in box-1

Answer (score 0):

This was my problem too, but i got it solved by javascript. first you need to identify which row you wanna make the column in it has equal height by adding class like `equal-height`, then you can use below function and call it when the window is loaded (since there is an image).

```
function equalizeColumnContentHeight(){
    if( window.innerWidth > 990 ){
        $(".equal-height").each(function(){
            //resetting height to auto
            $(this).find(".col-content").height("auto");

            var height = $(this).outerHeight();
            $(this).find(".col-content").height(height);
        });
    } else {
        $(".equal-height").each(function(){
            $(this).find(".col-content").height("auto");
        });
    }
}
```

```js
(function() {
  function equalizeColumnHeight() {

    // This should be the breakpoint when your layout break to block
    if (window.innerWidth > 480) {
      $(".equal-height").each(function() {
        //resetting height to auto
        $(this).find("[class^='col-']").height("auto");

        var height = $(this).outerHeight();
        $(this).find("[class^='col-']").height(height);
      });
    } else {
      $(".equal-height").each(function() {
        $(this).find("[class^='col-']").height("auto");
      });
    }
  }

  $(window).load(function() {
    equalizeColumnHeight()
  });


})(jQuery);
```

```css
@import "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css";
 .col-xs-6 {
  background: #bad455;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row equal-height">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/13307/screenshots/1824627/logotypes_1x.jpg">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```